# C++) About deduplication of set

Tags: c++, set

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int n1;
    int n2;
    
    A(int n1, int n2)
    {
        this->n1 = n1;
        this->n2 = n2;
    }
};

struct Cop {
    bool operator() (const A&a, const A&b) 
    {
        if (a.n1 > b.n1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};


int main(void)
{
    set<A, Cop> a;
    a.insert(A(4, 5));
    a.insert(A(4, 6));

    for (set<A>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << it->n1 << " " << it->n2 << endl;

    }

}
```

**result:**
4 5

As you can see, even though the n2 elements of the A structure are not the same, the (4, 6) element is deleted. Can I solve this through operator overloading?

Comment: Your comparator `Cop` only compares `n1` elements, so you don't need operator overload, you need to fix `Cop::operator()` implementation

Comment: If the identity is not based solely on `n1`, then by-definition the identity ordering functor is broken, since that is all it compares. The value of `n2` is disregarded purposely by *you* per how you wrote `Cop`.

Comment: '
struct Cop {
 bool operator() (const A&a, const A&b) 
 {
  if (a.n1 != b.n1)
   return a.n1 > b.n1;
  return a.n2 > b.n2;
 }
};
'

like this one?

Comment: You could also inlcude `<tuple>`, then change your `Cop` function `operator()` to simply `return std::tie(a.n1, a.n2) > std::tie(b.n1, b.n2);`. That assumes you want the same ordering for `n2` as you have for `n1`.